# How to display date in datagridview if you select date value between two datagrid picker

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, left-join, datetimepicker

Could you help me? Below is my code. I'm trying to display date from mysql database,when I select different date values from two dataGridPickers. I want to display all results who are between selected value from two dateTimePickers into datagridview.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try   
        {
            string date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string date2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
            string CmdString = "SELECT korisnici.ime_prezime, knjige.Naslov,DATE_FORMAT(datum_iznajmljivanja,'%y-%M-%d') AS datum_iznajmljivanja,DATE_FORMAT(datum_vracanja,'%y-%M-%d') AS datum_vracanja"
                               + " FROM iznajmljivanje"
                               + " LEFT JOIN korisnici ON iznajmljivanje.korisnici_id=korisnici.id"
                               + " LEFT JOIN knjige ON iznajmljivanje.knjige_id=knjige.id"
                               + " WHERE iznajmljivanje.datum_iznajmljivanja > " + date1 + " AND iznajmljivanje.datum_iznajmljivanja < " + date2
                               + " GROUP BY iznajmljivanje.datum_iznajmljivanja"; 
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(CmdString, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView4.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Could you point out what the problem is (Undesired results, error message, something else)?

Comment: Don't insert values into query directly. Use `SqlCommand` and mainly `Parameters`. There are dozens of issues if you don't.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate. Perhaps you meant to include the DISTINCT operator.